# How to access a variable from an ActionListener

Tags: java, variables, actionlistener

Is there a way for me to access a variable that was made inside of an ActionListener?  I want to access the variable in the main class.

```
  actionBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
             int Number = 0;  //Access this variable

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You could make it a global variable (i.e. declare it outside of the `actionListener`).

Comment: @Pushkin I can remember myself doing this earlier.  I ran into multiple problems with it having to be final, and then it wouldn't work.

Comment: can you give us more context about the problem? Basically, there are only one way: make the variable or the method, or that Listener into broader scope that accessible from your context.

Comment: @BachT Yes, sorry.  I meant that I wanted to assign the variable in the ActionListener even if it was already assigned globally.  Basically, I want to press the button and have that variable change to what I want.

Comment: Still not sure what you want. But normally, I will not let the Listener do that work, because i will push the "state-related" information into the Model 9in this case, may be the class that contain all the code you provided. Can you explain a little more details?

Comment: @BachT I can't explain much more details as of now,  I'm away from my computer.  Only have my phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are time when you want to return a value from the listener. In most cases it is best to have that as a member field in the class and access it. Sometimes it looks overkill to define a member variable. I find it often happening when I use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`. In those cases, I usually define an array of the type required (int this case `final Number[] value[1]`) and set the `value[0]` in the runnable.

Still I do not see how it is going to be useful in this case.